# Django wsgi.py Http 404 error

Tags: python, django, wsgi, controllers

I m new to Django, and presently using it for my company app. 
I m using wsgi to start off (required for the API). The index.html is able to load the js and css files, but when clicking on get 'Run' on the html, it gives an error code of 404.

--> GET/CurrentTime HTTP/1.1 404

in App.py:

```
from App import wsgi
app = wsgi.application
```

in wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'App.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^CurrentTime$', TestControllers.get_current_time),
```

...

in TestControllers.py

```
def get_current_time(req):
    return HttpResponse(datetime.now().strftime("%a, %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p"))
```

Can someone help? Appreciate it.

Comment: Is 'TestControllers' your django app? because urls need to be pointed to the views in your Django App's views.py file.  Like so - url(r'^CurrentTime$', <AppName>.views.get_current_time) You'd also have to import the views by writing so - import <AppName>.views at the beginning of your file.

Comment: What is app.py for? How are you serving this site? How is it configured in your webserver? Why do you have a separate "index.html" that is not part of the Django application?